# Алгоритм сетки для сапера

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, reactjs

Пишу на js игру сапер. Как мы знаем, при клике по определенной клеточке все клеточки которые касаются к ней проверяются на наличие мин и таким образом выводится подсказка или нет. Я задал массив из 100 клеточек и по средствам react отрендерил доску. Выглядит это дело примерно так:

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

.....

и тд.

Таким образом до 100 (прока пробная версия, 1,2,3 не включил для наглядности ибо текстовый редактор не позволяет размещать цифры дону под другой)

Для проверки срабатывания я повесил на событиет клика функцию которая окрашивает красным соприкасающиеся блоки с выбранным. Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу грамотно задать алгоритм по которому при выбере крайних значений, пометка красным переносится на другую строку. (если например выбрал 20 то  в ответ придет 9, 10 , 11, 19 , 20, 21, 29, 30, 31)

Прошу помощи, как избежать данного переноса? Если есть идеи как концептуально изменить принцип работы поля тоже будет полезно.

Comment: Для вашего случая *у* можно вычислить делением нацело на 10. Проверяйте что *у* не поменялся (т.е. `30-31` => `(30-1)/10` не равно `(31-1)/10` поэтому не считаем, а для `29-30` условие работать будет). А вообще... как вариант... если поле двухмерное - то и массив лучше делать двухмерным. Но проверка "выход за пределы поля" нужна в любом случае.

Comment: Это неплохое решение, но как я написал выше, это всего лишь тестовая версия с полем 10 на 10. Я планирую сделать несколько уровней сложности с различными величинами полей, например 15 на 15. Для данной ситуации данный метод увы не сработает.

Comment: Почему не сработает? Меняете 10 на 15 и всё будет ок. Вот деление нацело в js непомню только как. Лучше брать `(i-(i%10))/10` либо округление с Math.

Comment: Я думаю что можно просто проверять Number.isInteger(value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вашего случая у можно вычислить делением нацело на 10. Проверяйте что у не поменялся (т.е. 30-31 => (30-1)/10 не равно (31-1)/10 поэтому не считаем, а для 29-30 условие работать будет). А вообще... как вариант... если поле двухмерное - то и массив лучше делать двухмерным. Но проверка "выход за пределы поля" нужна в любом случае.

Например можно так

```
var ten = 10;// Ширина поля

function getmatrix(n) {
  var y =parseInt((n-1)/ten);  
  if (y!=parseInt(n/ten)) // справа нельзя
    return [n-ten-1,n-ten, n-1,n, n+ten-1, n+ten];// Матрица "лево"
  if (y!=parseInt((n-2)/ten)) // слева нельзя     
    return [n-ten,n-ten+1, n,n+1, n+ten, n+ten+1];//Матрица "право"
// в остальных случаях вся девятка
 return [n-ten-1,n-ten,n-ten+1, n-1,n,n+1, n+ten-1,n+ten, n+ten+1];
  }

 // Проверяем, что получилось
  Console.log(getmatrix(20).join(','));
```

Выход за пределы по координате y не проверял. На самом деле тут 8 случаев: выход за предел по вертикали 2 по горизонтали 2, и по вертикали и горизонтали одновременно 4. Но этих трех, наверно достаточно. Если нет - то можно добавить проверок.